# DB2: How to retain backups if automatic backup is enabled

Tags: backup, db2

Is there a way to retain the backups or configure the interval when they are deleted?
According the manuals it's not possible: "If backup to disk is selected, the automatic backup feature will regularly delete backup images from the directory specified in the automatic database backup configuration. Only the most recent backup image will be available at any given time, regardless of the number of full backups that are specified in the automatic backup policy file."

Sounds strange to me.

Comment: This really belongs on dba.stackexchange.com, even though the [question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006669/db2-how-to-retain-backup-images-when-automatic-backup-enabled) was put on hold and suggested it be here.

Comment: there's very good reason why ibm is pushing tsm with db2 and all other major enterprise level backup software vendors have db2 api to co-operate...

Answer (score 0):

This is set via the `NUM_DB_BACKUPS, REC_HIS_RETENTN, AUTO_DEL_REC_OBJ` database configuration parameters.

To prevent DB2 from removing a backup it is surprisingly simple - just move it out of the location specified in the recovery history file.